# Use generic interface for class cast without warning

Tags: java, generics, interface

Let's assume we we want describe a `Category` with a `Description` and a list of `Items`. Each `Item` also has one `Category`:

```
public interface Description
{
}
```

This interface is really simple. Describing `Category` with generic bounds
becomes more complicated, but it's no rocket engineering.

```
interface Category<D extends Description,
                   C extends Category<D,C,I>,
                   I extends Item<D,C,I>>
{
  public List<I> getItems();
  public void setItems(List<I> items);

  public D getDescription();
  public void setDescription(D description);
}

interface Item<D extends Description,
               C extends Category<D,C,I>,
               I extends Item<D,C,I>>
{
  public C getCategory();
  public void setCategory(C category);
}
```

Now I want to define an Interface to class-cast an object
(`SecretDescription` is an implementation of `Description`):

```
SecretDescription sd = new SecretDescription();
Description d = (SecretDescription)sd;
```

This of course works, but now the question:
How can I use `Category` without a warning?

```
Category c;
```

This gives me the warning:

```
Category is a raw type. References to generic type Category<D,C,I>
should be parameterized
```

Ok, but how can I parameterize this?

```
Category<Description,Category,Item> c;
```

This gives me the compiler error:

```
Bound mismatch: The type Category is not a valid substitute for the
bounded parameter <C extends Category<D,C,I>> of the type Category<D,C,I>
```

Comment: @ElliottFrisch are you saying that with `D extends Description` the first parameter cannot be `Description` itself and that it must be a proper sub=class of `Description`? That is incorrect.

Comment: Why do `Category` and `Item` need to follow [crtp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Answer (score 2):

```
SecretDescription sd = new SecretDescription();
Description d = (SecretDescription)sd;
```

Please don't make the unnecessary cast on the second line.

```
Category<Description,Category,Item> c;
```

The `C` parameter has a constraint: it has to at least be `Category< D, C, I >`.  The raw type `Category` does not live up to that constraint, hence the message.

When you use self-bounded types like this, you have to create at least one subclass or subinterface that refers to itself in the generic parameter to terminate the seemingly infinite regression.

```
interface ExampleCategory extends Category< Description, ExampleCategory, ExampleItem >{}
interface ExampleItem extends Item< Description, ExampleCategory, ExampleItem > {}
```

Note that once you set the parameter to something, erasure means you can't reset it to something else deeper in the hierarchy:

```
// causes a compile error
interface BetterExampleCategory
extends ExampleCategory, Category< Description, BetterExampleCategory, ExampleItem > {}
```

That is, despite my comment in @rgettman's answer, you are better off preserving these parameters until you have a concrete class, as in

```
interface ExampleCategory< C extends ExampleCategory< C, I >, I extends ExampleItem< C, I > > extends Category< Description, C, I > {}
interface BetterExampleCategory< C extends BetterExampleCategory< C, I >, I extends ExampleItem< C, I > > extends ExampleCategory< C, I > {}
```

which can lead to some pretty thorny code.  (If you need it for type safety, do it.  Java has no better answer sometimes.)

Comment: This is indeed thorny. A `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` perhaps also does the job. But now I have learned more on Java!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to the interfaces `Category` and `Item` directly as type parameters to `Category`, because the type parameters themselves need to parameterized, which leads to an infinite generics specification:

```
Category<Description, Category<Description, Category<Description, ...
```

You need types that specify the type parameters of the interfaces in their class definition.

```
class SecretCategory
    implements Category<SecretDescription, SecretCategory, SecretItem>
{ ... }
```

and

```
class SecretItem
    implements Item<SecretDescription, SecretCategory, SecretItem>
{ ... }
```

Then at least you could say

```
Category<SecretDescription, SecretCategory, SecretItem> c =
    new SecretCategory();
```

or even

```
Category<? extends Description, ? extends Category, ? extends Item> c2 =
    new SecretCategory();
```

Comment: There's no reason the extensions need to be concrete classes.

Comment: @JudgeMental True, they don't have to be concreted, just that the specify their type parameters in the class/interface definition.  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using generics at all?  It seems as though everything you want to accomplish can be done with plain old Objects as member variables and taking advantage of inheritance:

```
public interface Description
{
}

interface Category
{
  public List<? extends Item> getItems();
  public void setItems(List<? extends Item> items);

  public Description getDescription();
  public void setDescription(Description description);
}

interface Item
{
  public Category getCategory();
  public void setCategory(Category category);
}
```

Your `SecretDescription` can still be set as the description for a `Category` by virtue of the fact that it extends `Description`

Comment: The above example is simplified, at the end of the day I have some generic factories who don't know about the implementation classes.